# Converting List<Integer> to List<String>

Tags: java, string, collections, integer

I have a list of integers, `List<Integer>` and I'd like to convert all the integer objects into Strings, thus finishing up with a new `List<String>`.

Naturally, I could create a new `List<String>` and loop through the list calling `String.valueOf()` for each integer, but I was wondering if there was a better (read: *more automatic*) way of doing it?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

As far as I know, iterate and instantiate is the only way to do this.  Something like (for others potential help, since I'm sure you know how to do this):

```
List<Integer> oldList = ...
/* Specify the size of the list up front to prevent resizing. */
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(oldList.size());
for (Integer myInt : oldList) { 
  newList.add(String.valueOf(myInt)); 
}
```

Comment: The original poster seemed to indicate that he had thought of this but considered this solution too complex or tedious. But I'm hard-pressed to imagine what could be easier. Yes, sometimes you have to write 3 or 4 lines of code to get a job done.

Comment: But that binds you to ArrayList. Can this be done using the same implementation as the original list?

Comment: @Andreas oldList.getClass().newInstance() will do

Answer (score 107):

Using [Google Collections from Guava-Project](https://github.com/google/guava/), you could use the `transform` method in the [Lists](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html) class

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.base.Functions

List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);

List<String> strings = Lists.transform(integers, Functions.toStringFunction());
```

The `List` returned by `transform` is a *view* on the backing list - the transformation will be applied on each access to the transformed list.

Be aware that `Functions.toStringFunction()` will throw a `NullPointerException` when applied to null, so only use it if you are sure your list will not contain null.

Comment: It will be nice if there are more ready functions beside Functions.toStringFunction()

Comment: clean but maybe not as fast.. 1 extra function call per value ?

Comment: HotSpot can inline function calls - so if it's called enough, it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I don't downvote this because it is indeed a solution. But encouraging people to add a library dependency to solve such simple task is a no-go for me.

Comment: A potential problem with that is that the transformation is applied lazily (potentially many times). You may want to return `new ArrayList<>(Lists.transform(integers, Functions.toStringFunction()))` instead to avoid this,

Comment: The inverse if you stumbled upon this question looking for String -> Number: `Lists.transform(listOfStrings, Ints.stringConverter());`

Answer (score 107):

Solution for Java 8. A bit longer than the Guava one, but at least you don't have to install a library.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

//...

List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
List<String> strings = integers.stream().map(Object::toString)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For Java 11,

```java
List<String> strings = integers.stream().map(Object::toString)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
```

Still no `map` convenience method, really?

Comment: While this is a bit longer for the `toString` example, it ends up being shorter for conversions not supported by Guava's Functions library. Custom Functions are still easy, but it is significantly more code then this Java 8 stream

Comment: Here is the "reverse" way too, for future readers. Thanks trejkaz!        Collection<String> keys = blah blah blah;
            Collection<Integer> keyInts = keys.stream().map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 41):

What you're doing is fine, but if you feel the need to 'Java-it-up' you could use a [Transformer](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api/org/apache/commons/collections/Transformer.html) and the [collect method](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/), e.g.:

```
public class IntegerToStringTransformer implements Transformer<Integer, String> {
   public String transform(final Integer i) {
      return (i == null ? null : i.toString());
   }
}
```

..and then..

```
CollectionUtils.collect(
   collectionOfIntegers, 
   new IntegerToStringTransformer(), 
   newCollectionOfStrings);
```

Comment: CollectionUtils.collect(collectionOfIntegers, new org.apache.commons.collections.functors.StringValueTransformer());

But , StringValueTransformer uses the String.valueOf ...

Comment: Unless new work has been done on apache collections, they don't do generics.

Comment: This is really Java-ing-it down. This is not idiomatic Java, and more like functional programming. Maybe when we get closures in Java 8 could you call it idiomatic Java.

Comment: You definitely want to use Collections4 for that (not the old 3.x Collections) for support of generics: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#transform%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections4.Transformer%29

Comment: Defining a new class just to be "more OOP or idiomatic"... I don't see how this is better than the simple for-each loop. It requires more code and moves the functionality away (which could be mitigated by anonymous classes, but still). This functional style only starts to become useful when there's a decent syntax (i.e. lambda expressions since Java 8), like functional languages have provided it for decades.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using String.valueOf I'd use .toString(); it avoids some of the auto boxing described by @johnathan.holland

The javadoc says that valueOf returns the same thing as Integer.toString().

```
List<Integer> oldList = ...
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(oldList.size());

for (Integer myInt : oldList) { 
  newList.add(myInt.toString()); 
}
```

Comment: as pointed out by Tom Hawtin in the 'winning' answer, one cannot instance List<String> as it is only an interface.

Comment: Heh I knew that. Just I wrote the code without trying it. I'll fix it in my answer.

Answer (score 9):

The source for String.valueOf shows this:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Not that it matters much, but I would use toString.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a one-liner solution without cheating with a non-JDK library.

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(list.toString().replaceAll("\\[(.*)\\]", "$1").split(", "));
```

Answer (score 7):

Another Solution using Guava and Java 8

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
List<String> strings = Lists.transform(numbers, number -> String.valueOf(number));
```

Answer (score 4):

To the people concerned about "boxing" in jsight's answer: there is none. `String.valueOf(Object)` is used here, and no unboxing to `int` is ever performed.

Whether you use `Integer.toString()` or `String.valueOf(Object)` depends on how you want to handle possible nulls. Do you want to throw an exception (probably), or have "null" Strings in your list (maybe). If the former, do you want to throw a `NullPointerException` or some other type?

Also, one small flaw in jsight's response: `List` is an interface, you can't use the new operator on it. I would probably use a `java.util.ArrayList` in this case, especially since we know up front how long the list is likely to be.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<String> stringList = integerList.stream().map((Object s)->String.valueOf(s)).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)

Comment: @Adnan you're probably referring to Android usage. The OP was asking generally. So, Java 8+ should be sufficient

Answer (score 3):

Not core Java, and not generic-ified, but the popular Jakarta commons collections library has some useful abstractions for this sort of task.  Specifically, have a look at the collect methods on

[CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html)

Something to consider if you are already using commons collections in your project.

Comment: Never use Apache Collections. They are old, outdated, not type-safe, and poorly written.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more concise solution using the forEach method on the original list:

```
    List<Integer> oldList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(oldList.size());
    oldList.forEach(e -> newList.add(String.valueOf(e)));
```

Answer (score 2):

@Jonathan: I could be mistaken, but I believe that String.valueOf() in this case will call the String.valueOf(Object) function rather than getting boxed to String.valueOf(int).  String.valueOf(Object) just returns "null" if it is null or calls Object.toString() if non-null, which shouldn't involve boxing (although obviously instantiating new string objects is involved).

Answer (score 2):

I think using Object.toString() for any purpose other than debugging is probably a really bad idea, even though in this case the two are functionally equivalent (assuming the list has no nulls).  Developers are free to change the behavior of any toString() method without any warning, including the toString() methods of any classes in the standard library.

Don't even worry about the performance problems caused by the boxing/unboxing process.  If performance is critical, just use an array.  If it's really critical, don't use Java.  Trying to outsmart the JVM will only lead to heartache.

Answer (score 2):

An answer for experts only:

```
    List<Integer> ints = ...;
    String all = new ArrayList<Integer>(ints).toString();
    String[] split = all.substring(1, all.length()-1).split(", ");
    List<String> strs = Arrays.asList(split);
```

Comment: This works but at the expense of inefficiency.  Java Strings are two bytes per char, so the ", " adds a four byte fixed cost per integer before counting the integer itself.... among other things.

Comment: I think the regex might be more a problem in terms of raw CPU cycle efficiency. In terms of memory, I guess a reasonable implementation (assuming the "Sun" unreasonable implementation of `String`) will share the same backing array (from `all`), so will actually be really quite memory efficient, which would be important for long term performance. Unless you only want to keep one of the elements of course...

Answer (score 2):

[Lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) allows to do that in a very simple and readable way. For example, supposing you have a list of Integer and you want to convert them in the corresponding String representation you could write something like that;

```
List<Integer> ints = asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
Iterator<String> stringIterator = convertIterator(ints, new Converter<Integer, String> {
    public String convert(Integer i) { return Integer.toString(i); }
}
```

Lambdaj applies the conversion function only while you're iterating on the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid the "boxing overhead"; Java's faux generic containers can only store Objects, so your ints must be boxed into Integers.  In principle it could avoid the downcast from Object to Integer (since it's pointless, because Object is good enough for both String.valueOf and Object.toString) but I don't know if the compiler is smart enough to do that.  The conversion from String to Object should be more or less a no-op, so I would be disinclined to worry about that one.

Comment: the compiler is NOT smart enough to do that.  When javac runs, it actually strips out all generics type information.  The underlying implementation of a generics collection ALWAYS stores Object references.  You can actually omit the <T> parametrization and get a "raw" type.  "List l = new List()" versus "List<String> l = new List<String>()".  of course, this means that "List<String> l = (List<String>)new List<Integer>()" will actually compile and run, but is, obviously, very dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, a solution using the jsr166y fork-join framework that should in JDK7.

```
import java.util.concurrent.forkjoin.*;

private final ForkJoinExecutor executor = new ForkJoinPool();
...
List<Integer> ints = ...;
List<String> strs =
    ParallelArray.create(ints.size(), Integer.class, executor)
    .withMapping(new Ops.Op<Integer,String>() { public String op(Integer i) {
        return String.valueOf(i);
    }})
    .all()
    .asList();
```

(Disclaimer: Not compiled. Spec is not finalised. Etc.)

Unlikely to be in JDK7 is a bit of type inference and syntactical sugar to make that withMapping call less verbose:

```
    .withMapping(#(Integer i) String.valueOf(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is such a basic thing to do I wouldn't use an external library (it will cause a dependency in your project that you probably don't need).

We have a class of static methods specifically crafted to do these sort of jobs. Because the code for this is so simple we let Hotspot do the optimization for us. This seems to be a theme in my code recently: write very simple (straightforward) code and let Hotspot do its magic. We rarely have performance issues around code like this - when a new VM version comes along you get all the extra speed benefits etc.

As much as I love Jakarta collections, they don't support Generics and use 1.4 as the LCD. I am wary of Google Collections because they are listed as Alpha support level!

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't see any solution which is following the principal of space
>   complexity. If list of integers has large number of elements then it's
>   big problem.

```
It will be really good to remove the integer from the List<Integer> and free
the space, once it's added to List<String>.
```

We can use iterator to achieve the same.

```
    List<Integer> oldList = new ArrayList<>();
    oldList.add(12);
    oldList.add(14);
    .......
    .......

    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(oldList.size());
    Iterator<Integer> itr = oldList.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        newList.add(itr.next().toString());
        itr.remove();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Solution for Java 8. A bit longer than the Guava one, but at least you
> don't have to install a library.

Just in case, for those lucky folks using Java of version >= 16, there is no need for a verbose chain of calls like `.collect(Collectors.toList())` anymore, just use a new method from a Stream interface [`toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()):

```
List<String> strings = integers.stream().map(String::valueOf).toList();
```

So, now it's even shorter than Guava version :)

Answer (score -1):

I just wanted to chime in with an object oriented solution to the problem.

If you model domain objects, then the solution is in the domain objects.  The domain here is a List of integers for which we want string values.

The easiest way would be to not convert the list at all.

That being said, in order to convert without converting, change the original list of Integer to List of Value, where Value looks something like this...

```
class Value {
    Integer value;
    public Integer getInt()
    {
       return value;
    }
    public String getString()
    {
       return String.valueOf(value);
    }
}
```

This will be faster and take up less memory than copying the List.