# How to convert List of raw data type to List<String> using Java 7(and below) only

Tags: java, generics, java-7, type-conversion, raw-types

There are a lot of QA posts on similar topics like:

[Java: Converting lists of one element type to a list of another type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395816/java-converting-lists-of-one-element-type-to-a-list-of-another-type)

[How to transform List to another List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383624/how-to-transform-listx-to-another-listy)

However, all they use some additional libraries which is inappropriate in my case. I would like to find optimal solution using only Java 7 (and below) libs.

So let's say we've:

```
List list = new LinkedList(); 
list.add(2);
list.add("Mike");
list.add("John");
list.add(11);

transformer(list); // transform List to List<String>
list.get(0).toLowerCase();
```

How to implement `void transform(List list)` method ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383624/how-to-transform-listx-to-another-listy or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524/java-best-way-of-converting-listinteger-to-liststring

Comment: @J. Pichardo this isn't publication because the post that you mention taking into account solutions with usage of other libraries.

Comment: @JeanLee See the second one

Comment: @J.Pichardo thx but I  need that input and result collection was the same in my case `list` object.

Comment: The output cannot be the same list as the input, because you've got things that are not strings in the list.

Comment: You need your `List<Object>` to become `List<String>` at runtime?

Comment: @ J. Pichardo run-time is not necessary. the solution is related to anonymous classes ( lambda in java 8 ) . it is possible for me to change argument list of transform method but again input and output object should be the same `list`

Comment: @JeanLee you would still have `List<Object>` and would be unable to treat them as `String`.

Comment: This seems like homework. And to be honest, there is enough information out there that a google search would suffice. A minimal intellectual effort should be in order. It will help users :-}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to return a new `List<String>`, and assign it. Iterate the input `List`, and call `toString()` on each element - adding that to a new `List` for returning. Something like,

```
public static List<String> transformer(List list) {
    List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator iter = list.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        al.add(iter.next().toString());
    }
    return al;
}
```

Then you can call it like

```
List<String> stringList = transformer(list);
stringList.get(0).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: This will fail with primitive values

Comment: @J.Pichardo Primitive values cannot be added to a collection. They're autoboxed to the wrapper types.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch for your attention. but I  need that input and result collection was the same in my case `list` object.

Comment: @JeanLee But I need a pony, a Ferrari and Angelina Jolie. I think we're both going to need to accept what we can have instead.

Comment: @ Elliott Frisch the solution is related to anonymous classes. Is it possible for me to change argument list for transform method.

Comment: @JeanLee Generics are a **compile** time feature, at **run-time** (after **type-erasure**) there are [*erased*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). You simply cannot do `list.get(0).toLowerCase();`, you **could** do `list.get(0).toString().toLowerCase();` - but you don't need a *`transform`* method for that.

Comment: @Elliott: Since Angelina is available again, your “needs” have a higher chance than the OP’s need.

Comment: @Holger I'll just go pick her up in my Ferrari then. Or should I put a "free pony rides" in my yard, and just wait?

Comment: I don’t know her good enough to tell you what the best strategy is. But, by the way, why don’t you use the for-each loop here? `for(Object o: list)` works with raw types…

Comment: @Holger I focused on the "using Java 7(and below) only" part of the question. `Iterator` is old-school.

Comment: Well, the for-each loop exists since Java 5, the same version that also introduced Generics, which are a fundamental part of this question. There is no point in considering older versions…

Answer (score 3):

You could go over the list's contents and call [`String.valueOf(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) of each one:

```
List<String> result = new LinkedList<>();
for (Object o : list) {
    result.add(String.valueOf(o));
}
```

EDIT:
This can also be done inline with a [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html), if you're so inclined:

```
ListIterator iter = list.listIterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    iter.set(String.valueOf(iter.next()));
}
```

Comment: @Mureinik Thx for your attention. but I  need that input and result collection was the same in my case `list` object.

Comment: @JeanLee I've updated my answer to include such an example too.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make what you need. However, you can access to String methods by writing something like this `stringList.get(0).toLowerCase();`