# Create a Stream<CustomType> using a Stream<String>?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Assuming I have a `Stream<String>`, what is the most succinct way with which I could obtain a `Stream<CustomType>` where each element of `Stream<CustomType>` has each element of `Stream<String>` as value for the one of its member variables:

E.g.:

```
class CustomType {
    private String id;

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    } 
}

class Test {
    public static void main (String... args) {
        Stream<String> source = Stream.of("A", "B", "C"); 
        
        Stream<CustomType> result = source.map(s -> {
            CustomType obj = new CustomType();
            obj.setId(s);
            return obj;
        });  
    }
}
```

Is there a way to shorten this?

**Later edits**: Looking for a way other than overriding constructor of `CustomType`, and to avoid coding the boilerplate of manually creating `CustomType` objects `CustomType obj = new CustomType();` i.e. somehow have Stream API create `CustomType` objects for me so I could just specify what setter (e.g.: `setID()`) the `String`s should be set to.

Comment: Can you add a constructor to `CustomType`?

Comment: Yes, thanks!. I could take that approach. Are there also alternative ways that Java Stream API itself provides?

Comment: You can also write a factory method in `Test`, as the answer shows in the latest edit, but the stream API itself doesn't (and tbh, _cannot_) provide anything.

Comment: Thanks; I was interested in finding out whether Stream API itself was capable of cutting down on `new CustomType()`.  and transforming the Stream<String> into a Stream<CustomType> if I somehow indicated to it (e.g. by passing a Consumer) that each element of String-stream should be passed to a particular setter of CustomType. For emphasis, what I really want is to avoid boilerplate of creating the new CustomType objects..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting lists of one element type to a list of another type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395816/converting-lists-of-one-element-type-to-a-list-of-another-type)

Answer (score 4):

If you can change the constructor for your custom type, you can do:

```
class CustomType {
    private String id;

    public CustomType(String id) {
      this.id = id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    } 
}

class Test {
    public static void main (String... args) {
        Stream<String> source = Stream.of("A", "B", "C");         
        Stream<CustomType> result = source.map(CustomType::new);  
    }
}
```

If you can't add a new constructor, the best you can do is move the setting logic outside of the stream processor, like so:

```
class Test {
    public static void main (String... args) {
        Stream<String> source = Stream.of("A", "B", "C");         
        Stream<CustomType> result = source.map(Test::customTypeWithId);  
    }

    private static CustomType customTypeWithId(String id) {
        CustomType obj = new CustomType();
        obj.setId(s);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks; that does it, but if I don't implement a custom constructor, is there an alternative?

Comment: Edited to add an alternative if you can't change the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, from the answers that seems to be the only alternative. What I'm really after is to have Stream API create CustomType objects for me, instead of ever manually having to create them, so all I'll have to do is to specify (e.g. pass a Consumer defining) how to use the String elements in Stream<String>(i.e. pass them to setID() of elements of Stream<CustomType>)..

Answer (score 1):

For any `CustomType` you could do it like this.

- define a Function to create an instance and set the value;
- then call the method with the source Stream and that function to return the new Stream

```
Stream<String> source = Stream.of("A", "B", "C");

Function<String,CustomType> fnc = (str) -> {
        CustomType t = new CustomType();
        t.setId(str);
        return t;};

Stream<CustomType> stream = customStream(source, fnc);
    
public static <T> Stream<T> customStream(Stream<String> source,
        Function<String, T> fnc) {
    Builder<T> builder = Stream.builder();
    source.forEach(k -> builder.add(fnc.apply(k)));
    return builder.build();
}
```

Of course it would be better if your custom types implemented an interface that had `T setId(String s)` as the method.  Here is an example of that:

```
interface SetIDInterface<T> {
    public T setId(String s);
}

class CustomType implements SetIDInterface<CustomType> {
    public String id;
    
    public CustomType setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;   
    }
}

Stream<String> source = Stream.of("A", "B", "C");
Stream<CustomType> stream = customStream(source, CustomType::new);

    
public static <T extends SetIDInterface<T>> Stream<T> 
               customStream(Stream<String> source, Supplier<T> sup) {
    Builder<T> builder = Stream.builder();
    source.forEach(k -> builder.add(sup.get().setId(k)));
    return builder.build();
}
```