# Converting an int array to a String array

Tags: java, arrays, list, int

So I have this "list" of ints.  It could be a `Vector`, `int[]`, `List<Integer>`, whatever.

My goal though is to sort the ints and end up with a `String[]`.  How the int array starts out as is up in the air.

ex: 
Start with:`{5,1,2,11,3}`
End with: `String[] = {"1","2","3","5","11"}`

Is there anyway to do this without a for loop?  I have a for loop now for collecting the ints.  I would rather skip doing another for loop.

Comment: Please retag your question with the appropriate language.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid for loops?  Any solution that anybody comes up with will have some sort of loop, even if it's hidden behind a method call.

Comment: It says "This is for Java", it has a java tag, and it hasn't been edited - your comment seems pointless?!?

I don't think it's possible to complete this without a loop (a few actually since sorting can only be done through some sort of loop/iterative process).

Comment: @Rudi It may have been edited within 5 minutes of being posted, in which case the edit wouldn't show up.

Comment: Maybe you should convert your int as Strings within your first loop.

Comment: @ColinD ah - fair enough :)  It now reports it was edit 4 minutes later anyway *shrug*

Comment: Seems to be two operations. How do I sort? [`Arrays.sort`/`Collections.sort`] How do I convert an `in[]`/`List<Integer>` to a `String[]`? [see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524/java-best-way-of-converting-listinteger-to-liststring/61663#61663 ]

Comment: It's a pity you're not using C#: `(new[] {5,1,2,11,3}).OrderBy(n => n).Select(n => n.ToString())`

Comment: To treat your fear of multiple for loops, I would seek professional help. Start by reading Refactoring (Martin Fowler) and Working Effectively With Legacy Code (Michael Feathers)...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
int[] nums = {5,1,2,11,3}; //List or Vector
Arrays.sort(nums); //Collections.sort() for List,Vector
String a=Arrays.toString(nums); //toString the List or Vector
String ar[]=a.substring(1,a.length()-1).split(", ");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar));
```

**UPDATE:**

A shorter version:

```
int[] nums = {-5,1,2,11,3};
Arrays.sort(nums);
String[] a=Arrays.toString(nums).split("[\\[\\]]")[1].split(", "); 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Comment: I think this could be the answer.  I didn't want to interate through the list a second time because I'm already iterating to get the int list.  Thank you.

Comment: if your concerned about speed then its better to use the normal for loop once more because in Arrays.toString() they are using a for loop.Check the source(http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Arrays.java.html)  But if you just want your code to look small then ok,you can use the above code or another option is just write small function to sent an int[] as input and return String[] array as output.

Comment: The "[\\[\\]]" is a regular expression, right?  How did you know which one to use, and what exactly is it dictating?

Comment: The idea is to use `Arrays.toString`

Answer (score 14):

Use a `Stream` which is available from Java 8. To get a `Stream` instance with "list" of ints:

- For `int[]`

  - `IntStream intStream = Arrays.Stream(nums);` or
  - `Stream<Integer> intStream = Arrays.Stream(nums).boxed();` if you need the same class as bottom one.
- For any classes with `Collection<Integer>` interface (ex. `Vector<Integer>`, `List<Integer>`)

  - `Stream<Integer> intStream = nums.stream();`

Finally, to get a `String[]`:

```
String[] answer = intStream.sorted().mapToObj(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 8):

Can I use a `while` loop instead?

```
@Test
public void test() {
    int[] nums = {5,1,2,11,3};

    Arrays.sort(nums);

    String[] stringNums = new String[nums.length];
    int i = 0;
    while (i < nums.length) {
        stringNums[i] = String.valueOf(nums[i++]);
    }

    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[]{"1","2","3","5","11"}, stringNums);
}
```

Using JUnit assertions.

Sorry, I'm being flippant. But saying you can't use a `for` loop is daft - you've got to *iterate* over the list somehow. If you're going to call a library method to sort it for you (cf [Collections.sort()](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))) - that will be looping *somehow* over the elements.

Answer (score 5):

Simple solution using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
public List<String> toSortedStrings(List<Integer> ints) {
  Collections.sort(ints);
  return Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.transform(ints, 
      Functions.toStringFunction()));
}
```

Obviously, this solution (like any other) is going to use loops internally, but it gets it out of the code you have to read. You could also avoid changing the order in `ints` by passing the result of `Ordering.natural().sortedCopy(ints)` to `transform` instead of using `Collections.sort` first. Also, the `Lists.newArrayList` part is not necessary if you don't need to be able to add new elements to the resulting list.

The shortened version of that method body, with static imports:

```
return transform(Ordering.natural().sortedCopy(ints), toStringFunction());
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use a TreeSet, I have a (longish) one-liner for you (assuming `items` is the TreeSet):

```
final String[] arr =
    items.toString() // string representation
        .replaceAll("\\D+", " ") // replace all non digits with spaces
        .trim() // trim ends
        .split(" "); // split by spaces
```

Test code:

```
Set<Integer> items = new TreeSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(5, 1, 2, 11, 3));

// insert above code here

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 11]
```

---

**EDIT:**

OK, here is a different version that works with the int array directly. But unfortunately it's not a one-liner. However, it does keep duplicates and it's probably faster

**EDIT again:**

Bug fixed and negative numbers supported, as requested:

**EDIT once more**: only one regex pass and no trim

```
    final int[] in = { 5, 1, 2, 11, 3, 2, -5 }; // with duplicate
    Arrays.sort(in);
    final String[] out =
        Arrays.toString(in)
            .replaceAll("(?:\\[?)([-\\d]+)(?:\\]?)", "$1") // just remove [ and ]
            .split("\\s*,\\s*"); // split by comma

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(out));
```

Output:

```
[-5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 11]
```

**Or completely without regex** (apart from split()), but with one more step added:

```
final int[] in = { 5, 1, 2, 11, 3, 2, -5 }; // with duplicate
Arrays.sort(in);
final String stringRep = Arrays.toString(in);
final String[] out =
    stringRep.substring(1, stringRep.length() - 1).split("\\s*,\\s*");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(out));
```

Output:

```
[-5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 11]
```

Update: stripped whitespace from my last two solutions, hope you're happy now :-)

Comment: This won't work correctly for any array or list with more than 1 of the same element.

Comment: +1 @ColinD. `TreeSet` will sort the numbers for you but it will also remove the duplicates, which is not what is intended.

Comment: I know, but nobody said anything about keeping dupes

Comment: Lists and arrays (mentioned in the question) keep duplicates, so I feel like it's kind of implicit.

Comment: little changes needed for correctly handling negative numbers, and there is an undefined `arr` being used instead of `in`...

Comment: @seanizer: No need to handle the number's type in regex just remove the opening and closing braces and split with ", ".

Comment: @emil true, but I don't think that's any simpler

Comment: Check my answer.I told so because you wouldn't have to handle negative values.

Comment: Also leave a space after ',' other wise all numbers will have an extra space.

Comment: @emil, ok here we go again. whitespace is now stripped

Answer (score 3):

> I would rather skip doing another for
>   loop.

That's silly.  It's a silly desire and a silly basis for undertaking a code exercise.  If you can better express the qualities that you want your code to have, then we've got something to talk about - that it should be easy to read, say, or performant, or testable, or robust.  But "I'd rather skip it" just doesn't give us anything useful to work with.

Comment: Because I already loop to get the list.  Thanks for playing though.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/),

```
import fj.data.List;
import static fj.data.List.*;
import static fj.pre.Show.*;
.
.
.
final List<Integer> xs = list(5,1,2,11,3);
final List<String> ys = xs.sort(Ord.intOrd).map(
  new F<Integer, String>() {
    @Override public String f(final Integer i) {
       return String.valueOf(i);
    }
  }
);
listShow(stringShow).println(ys);
```

Comment: that's cool!! (if I had any remaining votes I'd upvote it) :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(5,1,2,11,3));
Collections.sort(list);
Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
  stringList.add(iterator.next().toString());
}
System.out.println(stringList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) [`MutableIntList`](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/list/primitive/MutableIntList.html):

```
String[] result = IntLists.mutable.with(5, 1, 2, 11, 3)
        .sortThis()
        .collect(Integer::toString)
        .toArray(new String[]{});

Assert.assertArrayEquals(
        new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "5", "11"}, result);
```

Or trading some readability for potential efficiency:

```
MutableIntList intList = IntLists.mutable.with(5, 1, 2, 11, 3).sortThis();
String[] result = intList.injectIntoWithIndex(
        new String[intList.size()], 
        (r, each, index) -> {
            r[index] = Integer.toString(each);
            return r;
        });

Assert.assertArrayEquals(
        new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "5", "11"}, result);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this problem using regular expression as follows:

```
int[] intArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
String str = new String(Arrays.toString(intArray));
String stripNoneDigits= str.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
String[] stringArray = stripNoneDigits.split("");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collections.sort()` and then iterate over the list and collect`String.valueOf()` each element.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29

For a Vector, you would first get a List with `Collections.list(Enumeration e)`.

For an array, you would use `Arrays.sort()` instead of `Collections.sort()`.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5b%5d%29

Comment: Oh, yes it is. I don't use `Vector` s that much as they are obsolete, so i didn't know they became `List` s. I remembered when you would iterate them with `Vector.elements()` (long ago).

Comment: Vector, Hashtable, StringBuffer: These classes are all somewhat obsolete but folks keep using them. New folks, too. I wonder where they learn that...

Comment: @seanizer:I have never heard StringBuffer to be obsolete.Can you refer to any article?

Comment: `StringBuilder` obsoletes `StringBuffer` for most cases.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply cast those values to String within the original for loop, creating a String array rather than an int array? Assuming that you're gathering your initial integer from a starting point and adding to it on each for loop iteration, the following is a simple methodology to create a String array rather than an int array. If you need both int and String arrays with the same values in them, create them both in the same for loop and be done with it.

```
yourInt = someNumber;

for (int a = 0; a < aLimit; a ++) {

String stringName = String.valueOf(yourInt);
StringArrayName[a] = stringName;
yourInt ++;

}
```

Or, if you need both:

```
yourInt = someNumber;

for (int a = 0; a < aLimit; a ++) {

String stringName = String.valueOf(yourInt);
StringArrayName[a] = stringName;
intArrayName[a] = yourInt;
yourInt ++;

}
```

I agree with everyone else. For loops are easy to construct, require almost no overhead to run, and are easy to follow when reading code. Elegance in simplicity!

Comment: There a some problems with your code. 1. of all, nobody uses a blank in a++ while it might work. Don't try to be individual in coding style! 2. What is yourInt, someNumber? They don't exist in the question, and you don't declare or explain them. 3. `casting` is very narrowed defined term in Java. There is no cast from String to Int, because Int isn't a subclass of String. 4. nobody uses `s[a]=String.valueOf (yourInt);`, but `s[a] = "" + yourInt;`. 5. Why the intermediate assignment to stringName? 6. Why violation of coding styles and using StringArrayName[a] instead of stringArrayName[a]?

Comment: 7. What a name, stringArrayName! While it is an array of ints as names. 8. no indentation. All those problems hide your simple, but elegant, if applyable, idea.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 way, no loops at all:

```
 // Given
int[] array         = {-5, 8, 3, 10, 25};
// When
String[] actual = Arrays.stream(array)
        .sorted()
        .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
// Then
String[] expected = {"-5", "3", "8", "10", "25"};

assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);
```

Answer (score -2):

Arrays.sort(nums);
var stringArray = (nums.toString()).split(',').map(String);

Comment: Don't think Java has the `var` keyword. This looks like JavaScript