# Conversion from Int array to string array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, linq-to-objects

When I am converting array of integers to array of string, I am doing it in a lengthier way using a for loop, like mentioned in sample code below. Is there a shorthand for this?

The existing question and answers in SO are about `int[]` to `string` (not `string[]`). So they weren't helpful.

While I found this [Converting an int array to a String array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619850/converting-an-int-array-to-a-string-array) answer but the platform is Java not C#. Same method can't be implemented!

```
int[] intarray =  { 198, 200, 354, 14, 540 };
Array.Sort(intarray);
string[] stringarray = { string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty};

for (int i = 0; i < intarray.Length; i++)
{
    stringarray[i] = intarray[i].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
int[] intarray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
string[] result = intarray.Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Works! Let me try to understand the code. The looping is being done here isn't it? but not explicitly! Each number in intarray is converted to string (x=>x.ToString()). Am I correct here?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Looping is done by [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) method.

Comment: Please edit the question only if it is really necessary and try to make all possible editions at once. exceeding certain number of editions may turn post into wiki! Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Try Array.ConvertAll

```
int[] myInts = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

string[] result = Array.ConvertAll(myInts, x=>x.ToString());
```

Comment: Way to do it without "using System.Data.Linq;" which was requested but is a bigger hammer than is really needed.

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

Linq version:

```
String.Join(",", new List<int>(array).ConvertAll(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Simple one:

```
string[] stringArray = intArray.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: String.Join is not required.

Comment: Select is Linq method, defined in Enumerable class. ConvertAll is defined in Array class (that exists even before linq).

Comment: that means no need to declare 
`using System.Linq;` if we are using CovertAll! thank you so much!

Comment: That means you can use this in `.Net 2.0` also..@InfantProgrammer'Aravind'

Comment: That's great! but well Just FYI, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138/linq-on-the-net-2-0-runtime

Comment: That is because .net3/3.5 are just additional libraries on .NET 2.0 core.

Comment: @Vishal, yes it is! and not preferable to implement in realtime! so I appreciate your answer! Upvoted for providing .Net2 solution!