# Convert Set<Integer> to Set<String> in Java

Tags: java, string, integer, set

Is there a simple way to convert `Set<Integer>` to `Set<String>` without iterating through the entire set?

Comment: Much the same as `List`s: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524/java-best-way-of-converting-listinteger-to-liststring/61663#61663

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You have to format each integer and add it to your string set.

Answer (score 13):

No. The best way is a loop.

```
HashSet<String> strs = new HashSet<String>(ints.size());
for(Integer integer : ints) {
  strs.add(integer.toString());
}
```

Something simple and relatively quick that is straightforward and expressive is probably best.

(Update:) In Java 8, the same thing can be done with a lambda expression if you'd like to hide the loop.

```
HashSet<String> strs = new HashSet<>(ints.size());
ints.forEach(i -> strs.add(i.toString()));
```

or, using Streams,

```
Set<String> strs = ints.stream().map(Integer::toString).collect(toSet());
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `toString` instead of `stringValue` ;)

Comment: @Peter That indeed I did. I must have been thinking of `Integer`'s `.intValue()`.

Comment: Theoretically, your code could throw a `NullPointerException` in the call to `toString()` as a `Set<T>` can contain a null value.

Comment: @Luke True, but, as this is an example, handling it would be unimportant and, honestly, I wouldn't handle it even in production code until it proved to be an issue. Why bother if you know the input set won't have any nulls?

Comment: @Luke, For this reason I prefer the shorter `""+integer` ;)

Comment: @CajunLuke: I agree that if you know the input Set won't have any nulls, there's no need to bother with the null-check. The question does not mention whether nulls are possible though, and online code-samples do sometimes end up copied-and-pasted into production code (where I absolutely disagree with your approach of waiting "until it proved to be an issue").

Comment: @Peter: that maps nulls to a `String` instance of `"null"` though, instead of the probably more accurate actual null value you would get with the longer `integer == null ? null : integer.toString()`.

Comment: @Luke, true, Another way to map null Integer is to an empty string, which works for loading text tables into a spreadsheet.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Instead of dealing with a much of extra method calls and a new StringBuilder, `String.valueOf(integer)` is faster and has the same result as `""+integer`.

Comment: @CajunLuke While a little faster, it is more work for the developer. If you concerned about speed you wouldn't be adding Integer as a String to HashSet.  You might be using a library which wraps an `int[]` to save the `int` as a primitive.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I never thought of wrapping an int[] to keep the primitive. I'm going to have to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 10):

use Java8 stream map and collect abilities:

```
 Set< String >  stringSet = 
   intSet.stream().map(e -> String.valueOf(e)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a decorator if you really don't want to iterate through the entire set

Comment: Can you provide an example? I'm not familiar with the concept of decorators.

Comment: How would you apply the decorator pattern in this scenario?

Comment: If we just wanted a Set<Integer> to look like a Set<String> but not create another set (say if only a fraction of the set is likely to be checked) you would create a subclass of AbstractSet<String> that would wrap the Set<Integer> and do the conversions in individual methods.

Comment: Well it would depends on Mat needs. For a single need (function), i will probably create a simple object containing the set and implementing my required function. For more than one need, I will probably choose another solution :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use Commons Collections' [TransformedSet](http://collections.sourceforge.net/api/org/apache/commons/collections/set/TransformedSet.html) or Guava's [Collections2.transform(...)](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#transform%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29)

In both cases, your functor would presumably simply call the Integer's toString().

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you have to iterate through the collection; especially when there is a conversion involved that isn't natural. i.e. if you were trying to convert from Set-Timestamp- to Set-Date-; you could achieve that using some combination of Java Generics (since Timestamp can be cast to Date). But since Integer can't be cast to String, you will need to iterate.

Comment: Presumably, someone disagreed with the "no" answers and feels that a wrapper/decorator is a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement `Set<String>` yourself and redirect all calls to the original set taking care of the necessary conversions only when needed. Depending on how the set is used that might perform significantly better or significantly worse.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) with Java 8:

```
Set<String> strings = IntSets.mutable.with(1, 2, 3).collect(String::valueOf);
```

This doesn't require boxing the int values and Integer, but you can do that as well if required:

```
Set<String> strings = Sets.mutable.with(1, 2, 3).collect(String::valueOf);
```

`Sets.mutable.with(1, 2, 3)` will return a `MutableSet<Integer>`, unlike  `IntSets.mutable.with(1, 2, 3)` which will return a `MutableIntSet`.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static <T> Set<T> toSet(Set<?> set) {
    Set<T> setOfType = new HashSet<>(set.size());
    set.forEach(ele -> {
        setOfType.add((T) ele);
    });
    return setOfType;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 + Guava (presumably no way to switch to Java 8).

```
new HashSet<>(Collections2.transform(<your set of Integers>, Functions.toStringFunction()))
```