# Does collections type conversion util methods already exist in any API?

Tags: java, generics, collections

```
interface TypeConverter<T, E> {
     T convert(E e);
}
class CollectionUtil() {
     public static <E> List<T> convertToList(List<E> fromList, TypeConverter<T, E> conv) {
     {
            if(fromList== null) return null;
            List<T> newList = new ArrayList<T>(fromList.size())  
            for(E e : fromList) 
            {
                newList.add(conv.convert(e));
            }
            return newList;
     } 
}
```

Above code explains converting from List of String to List of Integer by implementing TypeConverter interface for String, Integer. Are there already any collections conversion utility methods exists in any API like list to set and so on?

Comment: [Guava has one](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29). Related/dupe question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524/java-best-way-of-converting-listinteger-to-liststring

Comment: Such conversions are not safe. So they can not be part of Java API

Comment: @AmitD: I don't see the point of them being unsafe. In the shown code there is no explicit cast, this means that no type error will be thrown at runtime because of the strong static type checker.

Comment: @Jack According to me `TypeConverter` is unsafe because at some point of time developers will 'cast' values from one type to another and resulting `ClassCastExceptions`.

Comment: @AmitD: I don't see how it is possible if TypeConverter is generic on both parameter and return value and no casts are used. Using your assumption the whole Java language is unsafe because at some point you can always do a type cast :) Only a language that forbids type casting is inherently safe. You say that developers _will_, I say that developers _may_ but this is true everywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## In Guava:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
List<Integer> integers =
        Lists.transform(strings, new Function<String, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer apply(String input) {
                return Integer.parseInt(input);
            }
        });
```

#### Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

## In [Collections 15 package](http://collections15.sourceforge.net/):

```
final List<Integer> integers =
        ListUtils.transformedList(strings, new Transformer<String, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer transform(String s) {
                return Integer.parseInt(s);
            }
        });
```

#### Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>collections-generic</artifactId>
    <version>4.01</version>
</dependency>
```

## In [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/)

```
List<Integer> integers = List.list("1", "2", "3").map(new F<String, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer f(String s) {
        return Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
});
```

#### Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.functionaljava</groupId>
    <artifactId>functionaljava</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that this library uses different set of collections.

...bonus in Scala:

```
Seq("1", "2", "3") map {_.toInt}
```

Comment: +1 And note that the result of Guava's `Lists.transform` is a view, not a copy.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

- [FunctionalJava](http://code.google.com/p/functionaljava/) - [List.map](http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/fj/data/List.html#map%28fj.F%29)
- [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) - [Lists.transform](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29)
- [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) - look for conversion examples [here](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures)