# How to convert List<String> to List<Integer>?

Tags: java, string, list, generics

I am getting String of constants in `List<String>`. I need `List<Integer>`. By the basic way,
I will iterate and cast into Integer.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: What constants? `"123"`, something like this?

Comment: i'm afraid you have to create new list and parse and add each element to new list

Comment: Never heard there's any *better* (whatever *better* means) solution.

Comment: Why is this being voted down? It is a good question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope, there's no other way.

But casting is not possible in this case, you need to do use `Integer.parseInt(stringValue)`.

```
List<String> listStrings = ... 
List<Integer> listIntegers = new ArrayList<Integer>(listStrings.size());
for(String current:listStrings){
  listIntegers.add(Integer.parseInt(current));
}
```

Comment: Can we use like this? first assign List list = listStrings after that assign list to List<Integer>.

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to do this.

You could use the [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) and create a class which `implements List<Integer>`, but internally accesses your `List<String>` casting the values between Integer and String. As long as you fulfill all the contracts, any API which requires a `List<Integer>` will be able to work with this class just like with a native `List<Integer>`.

This might seem cumbersome and inefficient, but when you need to pass a `List<Integer>` to an API which only accesses some values of the list, it can be more efficient to cast some of them on-demand ("lazy evaluation") instead of casting all of them. It also saves memory, because you won't have both the string- and the integer representation of your whole list in memory at the same time.

Comment: You are thinking in patterns. I like that.

Comment: This is creative answer that actually makes this question worth it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(String str : listOfString) {
    listOfInteger.add(Integer.valueOf(str));
}
```

There's no direct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `Google Guava's Lists` class, you can do something as:

```
List<Integer> result = Lists.transform(stringList, new Function<String, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(@Nullable String input) {
        return Integer.parsInt(input)
    }
});
```

As far as I remember, it will transform each item lazily.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 there is some new solution:

```
List<Integer> listOfIntegers = listOfStrings.stream().map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not an explicit and direct way to change the parametrised type of a collection. You should create another one and transfer the data while modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

The other way around has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524/java-best-way-of-converting-listinteger-to-liststring).

Looks like looping is the only option. If you do not 'want' to loop yourself, there are some classes which can be used (e.g. from Apache Commons).

Answer (score 0):

It's not just a matter of casting, because `String` and `Integer` are fundamentally different objects.

You must loop through the list and parse each one int a new Integer:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(String numeric : stringList)
{
    intList.add(Integer.parseInt(numeric));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
List<String> strings = Lists.newArrayList("1", "2", "3");
List<Integer> ints = Lists.transform(strings, new Function<String, Integer>(){
    public Integer apply(String input) {
        return Integer.valueOf(input);
    }
});
```

Comment: Or for Guava 16.0+: `new ArrayList<>(Lists.transform(listOfStrings, Longs.stringConverter()))`

Comment: @LateralFractal: Could be even shorter, just: `Lists.transform(listOfStrings, Ints.stringConverter())`