# Java Cast Error While Looping Through Integer List?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, integer

I am making a program that loops through an Integer list (simple, duh).  The problem is, when I loop through and try to convert the Integer list to a String list, I get a `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` error.  Yes, String to Integer error, not Integer to String error.  I have no clue why or how this is happening, and I need help on how to fix it.

How I define the list:

```
public List<Integer> killsList;
killsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

How I call the method:

```
gc.setList("playerKills", gc.getStringListFromIntegerList(plugin.killsList));
```

How I add values:

```
plugin.killsList.add(1);
```

The error occurs on the `for (Integer num : list) {` line...

Code:

```
public ArrayList<String> getStringListFromIntegerList(List<Integer> list) {

    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

    plugin.console.sendMessage(list.toString());

    for (Integer num : list) {

        newList.add(String.valueOf(num));
        plugin.console.sendMessage(String.valueOf(num));

    }

    return newList;

}
```

Example:

```
public List<Integer> killsList;
killsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

plugin.killsList.add(kills);

gc.setList("playerKills", gc.getStringListFromIntegerList(plugin.killsList));

public ArrayList<String> getStringListFromIntegerList(List<Integer> list) {

    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

    plugin.console.sendMessage(list.toString());

    for (Integer num : list) {

        newList.add(String.valueOf(num));
        plugin.console.sendMessage(String.valueOf(num));

    }

    return newList;

}
```

Comment: I am going to assume that the issue is in the for loop statement(?). Try making num into a string, and then convert it into an integer within said loop. Because the failure in casting makes sense, you are requesting an integer to hold the values of a List<String>

Comment: If I try to make `num` a String, then I get a compile error that wants me to change it back to Integer.  I've looped through lists like this before (usually String lists), with no problem.

Comment: This post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524/java-best-way-of-converting-listinteger-to-liststring?rq=1 basically has the exact code I'm using, but doesn't get the error.

Comment: You may wish to delete obsolete comments. Now I assume that you don't pass an empty list into this method, that you fill it with ints first, correct? How exactly do you fill it?

Comment: .......... and what *exactly* do you fill it with? This is critical.

Comment: Post edited with code.

Comment: @AngryCupcake274 Since we are clueless, could you post a complete example where the error occurs? (please first remove all code that is not required to reproduce the error)

Comment: Yep, a [mcve] would be quite helpful

Comment: Complete mini-example added.

Comment: It's "complete" if I can copy it, paste it into my IDE, run it unaltered, and experience your error.

Comment: That's all the code required (for me) to get the error.

Comment: Great, but can I compile it? No. Can I run it? No. Can I fully understand your error? Regretfully, no.

Comment: Tomorrow I'll write a complete class just for diagnosing this error.

Comment: OK..... it's now "tomorrow"

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to get to it tomorrow.  I've been really busy.  The latest will be Thursday or Wednesday night.

Answer (score 1):

Proof of concept that your question is not yet adequate. Here is my [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using your code to try to catch your error:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> killsList;
        killsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            killsList.add(i);
        }

        ArrayList<String> strList = getStringListFromIntegerList(killsList);
        System.out.println(strList);
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getStringListFromIntegerList(List<Integer> list) {
        ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
        // plugin.console.sendMessage(list.toString());
        for (Integer num : list) {
            newList.add(String.valueOf(num));
            // plugin.console.sendMessage(String.valueOf(num));
        }
        return newList;    
    }
}
```

and it returns error-free:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Your error lies elsewhere in **code you've not shown us**, my guess by somehow putting a String in the input List. To solve it you'll need to create and post a valid MCVE, one that shows us the error.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that before you pass variable `list` to the above function, you cast it from a string list as `(List<Integer>) stringList` and the type of `stringList` is `List<String>`?

Comment: @AngryCupcake274 Could you please also show how you call the above method? There must be a wrong cast somewhere in the generic parameter. Are you not getting a compile-time warning about unsafe generic casts?